# Did the Arab League create a Joint Defense Council and a Permanent Military Commission?

Tags: military, political-history, defense, arab

Were the [Arab League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_League)'s Joint Defense Council and the Permanent Military Commission ever created?

There seems to be a lack of information concerning this topic on the internet, but by the [Treaty of Joint Defense and Economic Cooperation Between the States of the Arab League](http://avalon.law.yale.edu/20th_century/arabjoin.asp) (Articles 5 & 6), a Joint Defense Council and Permanent Military Commission should have been created in 1950.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Joint Defense Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_League#Military) (JDC) and the [Permanent Military Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutions_of_the_Arab_League) (PMC) of the [Arab League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_League#Military) were created in 1950, with the **JDC in existence until at least August 2015**. Since then, both bodies seem to have been superseded by or absorbed into other organizations.

There is no mention of either organization on the current [Arab League website](http://www.lasportal.org/Pages/Welcome.aspx), but **both organizations are mentioned on the [Arab League 24th Summit](http://arableaguesummit2013.qatarconferences.org/arab-league.html) page** (**March 2013**) as two of the four Defense and Economic Cooperation Bodies.

On [the PMC](https://tcf.org/content/report/too-important-to-give-up/?session=1),

> Over the decades, it has been as effective as its parent
> organization in achieving security cooperation between Arab League
> member states — which is to say, not very effective. Regional events
> quickly caught up with this formal attempt at security cooperation as the Egyptian monarchy fell to a military coup in 1952 and the Arab
> Cold War hardened divisions between nationalist republics and
> conservative monarchies. A decade on, the original signers of the
> treaty could be split almost evenly between the two camps—Egypt, Iraq,
> and Syria in the nationalist column, and Saudi Arabia, Jordan, and
> Yemen among the leading monarchies. Lebanon was caught in the middle.

Recent references to the JDC and the PMC are scarce and reports on Arab military co-operation usually don't even mention either organization (for example, this **March 2015** report on the [formation of a unified military force](https://www.reuters.com/article/mideast-arabs-communique/update-5-arab-summit-agrees-on-unified-military-force-for-crises-idUSL6N0WV03T20150329)). One of the most recent reports (**August 2015**, with reference to the March meeting above) on the JDC only serves to underline how little has been achieved:

> The Joint Defence Council meeting scheduled for Thursday at the Arab
> League headquarters in Cairo has been postponed as requested by the
> Saudi government...
>
> The Joint Defense Council meeting was to draft a protocol for an Arab
> Joint Force.
>
> The General Secretariat added that the meeting was postponed to
> unspecified date after the secretary general consulted Egypt, the
> current president of the Arab Summit.

*Source: '[Arab League postpones Joint Defence Council meeting](http://english.ahram.org.eg/NewsContent/1/64/138913/Egypt/Politics-/Arab-League-postpones-Joint-Defence-Council-meetin.aspx)' (ahramonline)*

This lack of achievement on co-operation has not just been evident in military matters but also in the area of planned economic integration, as the report *[Middle East Dilemma: The Politics and Economics of Arab Integration](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.476.2184&rep=rep1&type=pdf)* (Center for Contemporary Arab Studies, Georgetown University - pdf) makes clear.

Current attempts, encouraged by the Trump administration, at forming what is being dubbed an '[Arab NATO](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-egypt-military-arabs/egypt-hosts-arab-military-exercises-in-what-could-develop-into-an-arab-nato-idUSKCN1N52HS)' or ["Middle East Strategic Alliance" (MESA)](https://www.defensenews.com/global/mideast-africa/2018/08/29/what-are-the-chances-an-arab-nato-will-work/) do not seem to make any mention of either the JDC or the PMC.